# How can you use JQuery to verify that a radio button was clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

This Jquery statement has 2 functions.  The second function isAnswered is where I am getting the issues.  It somehow doesn't see that the radio button is clicked and I am not sure why (maybe the newer version of Jquery?)?

JQUERY has 2 functions but 2nd one is the issue - always comes back false for show_action:

```
//[F] button clicked
$(".upload_files").click(function() {
  var disabled = $(this).attr("do_disable");
  fileClick(audit_instance_id, this, disabled);
});

function fileClick(audit_instance_id, data, disabled) {
 var questionID = data.id;
 var show_action = isAnswered(questionID);// This always comes back false
 if (show_action) {
  $('#question_id').val(questionID);
  $('#uploaded_files_' + questionID).toggle();
  //problem after this
  var visible = $('#uploaded_files_' + questionID).is(':visible');
  if (visible === true) {
    var params = {
      'action': 'get_files',
      'audit_instance_id': audit_instance_id,
      'question_id': questionID
    };
    $.post('ajax/perform_audit.php', params, function(data) {
      displayFiles(data, questionID, audit_instance_id, disabled);
    });
    show_action = false;
  }
} else {
  alert("You must answer the Audit question before adding a file.");
}
return false;
}  


function isAnswered(comment_id) {
 var show_action = false;
 $("#options_" + comment_id + " input, #options_" + comment_id + " textarea").each(function(){

//This part seems to be teh issue or the .each above

  if($(this).attr("type") == "checkbox" || $(this).attr("type") == "radio"){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
          show_action = true;
      }
   } else if($(this).attr("type") == "text" || $(this).is("textarea")){
      if($(this).val()){
          show_action = true;
      }
   }
 });
return show_action;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a title='Upload file' href='#!' id=$row[questionID] class='btn btn-default btn-xs upload_files'>

<input name="4117" value="1983" id="option_1983" type="radio">
<input name="4117" value="1984" id="option_1984" type="radio">
```

Comment: try in if statement - $(this).prop('checked')

Comment: How could I see if type=radio is checked?

Comment: `if($(this).prop('checked')){show_action = true;}`

Comment: Where is the HTML with `id="options_XXX"`?

Comment: input   id="option_1984"  It breaks it down.....

Comment: That's `option_`. Your code is looking for `options_`. And it expects it to be a container whose contents are inputs or textareas.

Answer (score 0):

a thorough way to check it would be to validate if anything is checked e.g.

```
   $('#trigger').click(function() {
    if (!$("input[type="radio"][name='name']:checked").val()) {
       alert('Nothing is checked!');
        return false;
    }
    else {
      alert('A radio button is checked!');
    }
  });
```

To use the console log just use e.g. `console.log("nothing is checked");` and then when you press f12 you will see the messages and any errors too.

```js
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    if (!$("input[type='radio'][name='fruit']:checked").val()) {
       alert('Nothing is checked!');
        return false;
    }
    else {
       var selVal = "";
selVal = $("input[type='radio'][name='fruit']:checked").val();
      alert('A radio button ' + selVal + ' is checked');
    }
  });

//if we take out the [name='fruit'] bit the function will work for both input sets
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
     <input name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana" type="radio">
<label for="banana">banana</label>
<input name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple" type="radio">
<label for="apple">apple</label>
<input name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange" type="radio">
<label for="orange">orange</label>
<br><br>
    <input name="boy" value="Mark" id="Mark" type="radio">
<label for="Mark">Mark</label>
<input name="boy" value="Dan" id="Dan" type="radio">
<label for="Dan">Dan</label>
<input name="boy" value="Harry" id="Harry" type="radio">
<label for="Harry">Harry</label>
<br><br>

<input id="trigger" type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/vmMkZ223j8  I was trying your code out and could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just a sec, just saw msg, am on phone have to wake up laptop!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rakepehoza/edit?html,js,output works in jsbin? only diff is single quotes around 'radio' .. but you didn't have a #trigger defined, i added one as a button

Comment: works your way aswell http://jsbin.com/gunezezopo/edit?html,js,output with just :radio

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if ($(this).checked){
}
```

You could also try adding in some logging for development to make sure the component_id coming in is what you expect.

Comment: I was using alert(dataofsomesort); mainly, how do you have it log?

Comment: I use alert as well.  It just helps to know what the value is.  You can then use your browsers development tools (F12) to ensure that the <input> for the radio button has the same id as what is being shown in the alert dialog.

Comment: The inspector...  I love using that!  Is there something to pay attention to in there like the Network tab?

Comment: As long as your screen isnt being changed dynamically you should be able to just inspect the element once it has been loaded on screen.  You shouldn't need to monitor it.

Comment: This is not correct. `$(this)` is a jQuery object, `.checked` is a DOM property. It should be `if (this.checked)`.